# C++ How to warning about difference between argument names in function declaration and definition

Tags: c++, static-analysis

Is there a way to get warned about missmatching of the argument names between a function declaration and its definition?

*Declaration*

```
double divide(int a, int b);
```

*Definition*

```
double divide(int b, int a)
{
    return a / b;
}
```

For a user, that use the function `divide`, will expect a / b as a result and not b / a.

I know, the compiler can't do that, but are there some static analysis tools that can do that? If yes, which ones?

Comment: arguments are positional only in C. I have tested with `-Wall` and no luck BTW.

Comment: For the simple reason that if somebody doesn't know how the function is declared, could get unexpected results from it. For example a/ b != b/a

Comment: of course, that is a real problem. But in C that cannot be done. I'm sure some code analysers like ClokWork or Logiscope propose such checks.

Comment: @lucab0ni, this is a very strange example. Why do you think a user would "expect a/b", as you say? If I call `divide(2,3)` and I see the declaration `double divide(int a, int b)`, why would I assume `2/3` instead of `3/2`

Comment: Perhaps you mean the declaration `double divide(int numerator, int denominator);`? This would cause the reader to make assumptions about the meaning of the parameters

Comment: A good code review?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use clang-tidy. Calling it a compiler is a bit of a stretch, but maybe there is an option to make clang emit clang-tidy warnings. The specific option you want is [`readability-inconsistent-declaration-parameter-name`](http://clang.llvm.org/extra/clang-tidy/checks/readability-inconsistent-declaration-parameter-name.html).

Answer (score 0):

Compiler doesn't care about argument names in your declatation, you even can write `void foo(int, int);`, so there is no mismatch, and there is no such warning. If you for some reason finding this mismatch confusing, just omit argument names in declarations.

Comment: "just omit argument names in declarations.", I think the reason he wants the warning is so the function is clear just by looking at the declaration.

Comment: @George, perhaps. But what is "clear" about variables called "a" and "b"? I see a `division` of two integers called `a` and `b`.

Comment: @AaronMcDaid: I think a more realistic example would be `void copy(int *src, int *dest)` swapping the names would be *bad*.  (Yes, I realize `src` should be `const int*`).

Answer (score -1):

Are you just interested in checking existing code, or do want to ensure that the code avoids this problem and are willing to redesign the interfaces?

In the latter case:

If you have many arguments of the same type then inconsistencies can be a problem (and I have seen worse than your example):

```
void foo(bool fast, bool small, bool trivial);
foo(true, false, false);
```

What you are asking for is a way to ensure that declaration and definition of foo are consistent - but you ignore inconsistencies between call and declaration.

A different solution is to instead create an argument-struct with setRoutines. Something like:

```
struct FooArg {
   bool fast, small, trivial;
   FooArg &setFast(bool fast_) {fast=fast_;return *this;}; 
   ...
};
void foo(FooArg const&);
foo(FooArg().setFast(true).setSmall(false)...);
```

You then avoid the inconsistency between declaration, definition, and call, but have to be more verbose.
(I am sure there is an answer about this technique somewhere.)

Comment: I'm just interested in checking the code. In my actual case, the declaration is generated by a tool, instead the definition is done manually.

Comment: And I assume that having the tool generate stub-definitions will be too much work, especially if the tool has to be re-run to generate new declarations- while keeping some of the existing definitions.